# Android Studio - Pasar la información de los campos de 2 tablas distintas

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Tengo un problema que me parece que su solución es sencilla pero ya intenté con todo lo que se me ocurrió y no pude lograrlo.

En mi clase BaseDeDatos tengo este método:

```
    public List<Pets> mostrarPets(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM pets", null);
    List<Pets> pets= new ArrayList<>();
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            pets.add(new Pets(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),
                    cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5)));
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return pets;
}
```

El cual me trae ciertos campos de la tabla "pets", luego lo llamo en mi clase MainActivity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pets);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvPets);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    BaseDeDatos tablaPets = new BaseDeDatos(getApplicationContext());

    enganchePet = new RecyclerViewEnganche(tablaPets.mostrarPets());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(enganchePet);
```

De esta manera logro pasar los valores de esos campos a otras activities mas adelante para usarlos. Mi problema es que necesito hacer lo mismo con un valor de otra tabla que "reservas", entonces lo más cerca que estuve de lograrlo fue haciendo otro método abajo del anterior en la base de datos pero para la tabla "reservas", utilizando el mismo List que en el metodo anterior. El método es el siguiente:

```
public List<Pets> mostrarReservas(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM reservas", null);
    List<Pets> reservas= new ArrayList<>();
    if(cursor2.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            reservas.add(new Pets(cursor2.getString(0)));
        }while (cursor2.moveToNext());
    }
    return reservas;
}
```

Pero cuando lo pretendo llamar desde el MainActivity, me doy cuenta de que no puedo llamar a dos métodos en ésta linea:

> enganchePet = new RecyclerViewEnganche(tablaPets.mostrarPets());

o llamo al tablaPets.mostrarPets() o llamo al tablaPets.mostrarReservas().

Probé llamando por separado a cada uno y me pasa lo más bien la info que necesito, pero lo que necesito es pasar la info de las dos tablas (o de los dos metodos).

Mi duda es cómo puedo hacer para pasar la información de los campos de las 2 tablas ("pets" y "reservas")? y no sólo de una, para usarla mas adelante

PD: Si necesitan que agregue las clases enteras me dicen, sólo puse los métodos para evitar confusiones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu código, tanto mostratPets como mostrarReservas devuelve una List de Pets. Esto es correcto?

Si lo fuese, recuerda que no tienes por qué llamar funcionas de forma anidada, sino que puedes hacerlo en varias líneas.

```
List<Pets> completeList = new ArrayList<>();
completeList.addAll(tablaPets.mostrarPets());
completeList.addAll(tablePets.mostratReservas());
enganchePet = new RecyclerViewEnganche(completeList);
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias @Mauro Curbelo! estuve todo el fin de semana peleando con esto y no podía solucionarlo. Te agradezco mucho de verdad!!